# Use VB Variable inside a batch file

Tags: vb6, dos

I created the following batch file using VB:

```
Open sBatchFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, "@ECHO OFF"
    Print #1, "ECHO Converting Excel Files to PDF, Please wait..."
    Print #1, "batchpdf ""\\Tiltonsrv1\officeplantshared\Schedule_3.xls"" ""\\Tiltonsrv1\officeplantshared\SHIFT_SCHEDULES\"" &fileName& "
    Close #1

    i = Shell(sBatchFile, vbMaximizedFocus)

    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

But the variable fileName isn't recognized. Am I putting it into the file correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Open sBatchFile For Output As #1 
Print #1, "@ECHO OFF" 
Print #1, "ECHO Converting Excel Files to PDF, Please wait..." 
Print #1, "batchpdf ""\\Tiltonsrv1\officeplantshared\Schedule_3.xls"" ""\\Tiltonsrv1\officeplantshared\SHIFT_SCHEDULES\" & fileName & """ "
Close #1 

i = Shell(sBatchFile, vbMaximizedFocus) 

Application.Quit
```

Comment: Sorry, I still had the quote in the wrong spot, try my last edit